# Adding a multivalued, commas separated String to Solr isn't working

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to add a multivalued content to Solr index. The original String contains values seperated by ",".

```
<fieldtype name="commas_type" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=",\s*"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=",\s*"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldtype> 


<field name="keywords" type="commas_type" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" />
```

But instead of getting :

```
 <doc>
   <arr name="keywords">
     <str>Agile</str>
     <str>Kanban</str>
     <str>Clojure</str>
     <str>Datomic</str>
   </arr>
 </doc>
```

I'm getting:

```
 <doc>
   <arr name="keywords">
     <str>Agile, Kanban</str>
     <str>Clojure, Datomic</str>
   </arr>
 </doc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not change the Stored values for the Original data.
The pattern tokenizer would only be applied to the index values. So if you check your index for the indexed terms you would get the values splitted by ,.
However, the values returned by Solr would always be the values fed to it.

You would need to handle it at client side.

Comment: Re-indexing Solr using the previous configuration will solve the problem ? Because I tried this but still getting the same result.

Comment: Yup this will never change. As Solr stores the Original values as is and only modifies the indexed terms as per the configurations in schema.xml. So it is not going to help. If you want the values splitted it needs to be done at the client side.

Comment: Why I'm not getting any result when trying to search the previous field using the suggest component ? I'm mean any result . I got nothing at all.