# Searching a comma-separated list in Solr using Spring Boot

Tags: java, groovy, solr, spring-boot, criteria

I have an object `Foo` with a `List<String>` property names:

```
class Foo {
    List<String> names = []
}
```

In my `schema.xml` for Solr, I have it configured as a string:

```
<field name="names" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I am then trying to perform a search on it, where, as long as ANY of the values match ANY of the ones in the list, I expect a hit:

```
new Criteria('names').in(filter.names)
```

However, because the values are stored as a comma-separated String in Solr, I am not getting back any results.

Is there something I should change to be able to split or parameterize the field into a list so that I can perform my search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make the field in solr to be multi-valued.

Comment: Would that make it a list if it's comma-separated?  I thought multiValued meant that the field may just be declared multiple times.

Comment: Yes this should be handled during index time, to make sure the data stored in the index is in Multi-valued format. Here is one way to handle it during the data load if you can not change the data format at source. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278593/adding-a-multivalued-commas-separated-string-to-solr-isnt-working

Comment: Yep, this worked -- the key is to make sure that the fields show up multiple times (and not just comma-separated).